# Extending Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I would like to extend jupyter by adding functionality, for instance comparing two notebooks, to a new tab like in the picture below. Is there any way to do it like this? Do you suggest any other way?

[image]

Thanks!!